# Views field view: contextual filter send value only one time

Tags: views

I have view which is displaying only 2 nodes.
I add views field view to another view which is display all nodes which are from another content type but with the same date as his parent node. I filter it by contextual filter and everything is working but I have a problem with second parent node. It is display fine but it looks like that it is passing contextual filter from the first parent and to parent 2 view is displaying child from parent 1. Where is the problem? Is it passing contextual filter only one time and after that is it using only this contextual filter?
for 1 parent I am passing contextual filter [%field_date] with value 2012-10-13 and it showing me all nodes with this date.. it is good. But for second parent I need value 2012-10-14 and it looks like it is still 2012-10-13 from first passing of contextual filter.

now I have this result

```
parent 1
    - child 1 of parent 1
    - child 2 of parent 1
    - child 3 of parent 1 ....
parent 2
    - child 1 of parent 1
    - child 2 of parent 1
    - child 3 of parent 1 ....
```

but I need something like this:

```
parent 1
    - child 1 of parent 1
    - child 2 of parent 1
    - child 3 of parent 1 ....
parent 2
    - child 1 of parent 2
    - child 2 of parent 2
    - child 3 of parent 2 ....
```

Thanks a lot for all your replies :)

*updated*

---

after hours of testing I thing that there is a problem with passing date from parent field date. When I get it as contextual filter into child view with [!field_date] and after that I use it in header of view with %1 it is blank. I need to use it with !1 paramater and ther it look good. But in contextual filters of child view I cant spcify in which format I want to use parameter. I think there is a problem with sending paramater from parent to child view, but I cant find it.